# What would the total current requirements be for these items?

Tags: led, adafruit, current, rgb-led

I'm using [5 of those 8mm NeoPixels](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1734) + a [5V Trinket](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1501).

I'm trying to get a rough estimate of the current requirements that would have, assuming all 5 NeoPixels were running at full brightness "white" (255 RGB).

I'm voltage-regulated to about 150 mA from the Trinket and my current hunch is that those NeoPixels need more than that, but trying to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the data sheet each LED takes a maximum of 3*20mA, so you are pulling 300mA.  You  are going to need a bigger power supply :(